# Why init block not executing when a class inherited another open class Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin, init, superclass

I have **BaseClass** like this :

```
open class BaseClass(private var context: Context) {
      init{
         println("BaseClass init called")
      }
}
```

And **ChildClass** like this:

```
class ChildClass(private var context: Context) : BaseClass(context) { 
      init{
         println("ChildClass init called")
      }
}
```

So call it like this:

```
context?.let { ChildClass(it) }
```

But not called any **init** functions.

Comment: Can you try with debugging?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman not print any text in logcat.

Comment: is it spelling error? your class name is ChildClass, but you create ChildeClsss, i test your code and everything was okey

Comment: Simple, your context is null then.

Comment: I call it in RecyclerView call back, then tap on one item in callback listener in fragment i call ChildClass, i think i lost my state in RecyclerView callback. is it possible?

Comment: @reza_khalafi, Your code is absolutely fine. Can you check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`println` print the log in **Console**. To print log in **logcat**, you have to use `Log.` like:

```
init{
    //println("BaseClass init called")
    Log.v("TAG", "BaseClass init called")
}
```

Comment: yes, Tnx i think i must keep state in fragment because context is null

Comment: Now how to keep context in fragment kotlin

Comment: That is different things. You should create another post with your fragment code from where you call this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713626/how-to-put-serialize-and-get-serializecontext-in-kotlin-android

Answer (score 1):

I think your context is null in this line:

`context?.let { ChildClass(it) }`