# How to put serialize and get serializeContext in Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, android-recyclerview, onsaveinstancestate

I want save and keep my state in fragment because when tap on recyclerView items and back to fragment with listener i lost my Context and my context in fragment is **null**.
 So i try to keep my context like this:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putSerializable("SaveContext", context)
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize your `context` inside `fragment`?

Comment: WHAT?? Do not do that. This is a too bad practice.  Instead, find the reason behind context being null. Look the place where you initialize the context. If you are using context before initialising.

Comment: This can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987649/why-getcontext-in-fragment-sometimes-returns-null/47987701#47987701

Comment: @PankajKumar i set that code but when come back from listener in my fragment mContext is null ...

Comment: Without looking into your code, it is impossible to find out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your `context` correctly. Check below as for example

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {

    private var mContext: Context? = null

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        mContext = context
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        mContext = null
    }

    fun callbackListener() {
        mContext?.let { 
            //do your operation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not worked for me... mContext when i return from tap item will be null.

Comment: Please add your implementation for further investigation